# String Intern Pool

Tags: .net, vb.net

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx) advises that "The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a table, called the intern pool, **that contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program**. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a particular value only exists once in the system."

Why then does this `String.IsInterned` call, in the example below, not return a reference to the constant?

If I uncomment the first `Console.WriteLine` method call, the reference is returned.  Additionally if I don't declare the test variable as a constant, the reference is returned.  Why aren't constants interned?

```
Module InternTest
    Private Const test As String = "wwwww"
    'Private test As String = "wwwww"

    Sub Main()
        'Console.WriteLine(test)
        Console.WriteLine("interned = " & String.IsInterned(createString()))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Function createString() As String
        Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
        sb.Append("w")
        sb.Append("w")
        sb.Append("w")
        sb.Append("w")
        sb.Append("w")
        Return sb.ToString
    End Function
End Module
```